# How good is the wordpress templating system?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, wordpress-theming, template-engine, templating

I'm currently working on a PHP project using CodeIgniter as my framework. I took a look at a few templating systems I could probably use - Strogen's Templating System (currently used in PyroCMS - if I'm not wrong), Twig, Smarty etc.

But I have decided to go on my own to build one from scratch. Since I have experience dealing with Wordpress templates, I was thinking of creating something similar.

To give you a run down of how wordpress themes work - Wordpress has a set of functions (Theme functions) that help gather data. I was wondering if following the same would be a good idea for my project as well?

If I did create such template functions which I would be calling within my views, would it work against the MVC principles? And would it affect the performance in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with MVC, models do the db interactions, views display the data, and controllers are the go-between. If you created your "template functions" in the controllers, I suppose you would be complying with MVC. If you wanted to say, create a library or helpers to do the gathering of/manipulation of data, you would not be complying with MVC convention. AFAIK, it's a matter of preference which way you choose. As far as performance, you could use profiling to test which is better.

However, if your aim is to build a templating system for CI that is similar to WP just because you are familiar with the way WP templating works, I'd proffer that it would likely take you substantially less time to learn a new one than build your own. I'd also imagine it would take much less time to learn the new one than it did to learn the WP one.

Also, I think pyro uses a combination of Phil's templating and smarty, but not positive. Phil has a templating system available for CI here: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template May be worth checking out.

cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Storm. I decided to use the wordpress templating style not just because I'm familiar with it - also because my templates would be independent of the controller. In the sense that if I was to include another widget in my theme, I needn't edit my controller to fetch it for me. The functions in the template would do it right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... CI widgets? WP widgets? CI has widget/module availability where the widget/module are self-contained and can be called from a view. This means you can add, for instance, a login box to your view without messing with the main pages' controller. See if this helps: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/109584